# How do I access one field in a JSON file used for force directed?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am developing a forced network based on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045#index.html but using a JSON file of the following format:

```
{"organizations":[
   {"member":
      {"name":"Green 13",
       "target":"TCAN",
       "category":"community group",
       "source":"G13"}
   }, ....
```

As you can see the root object is "organizations" and the top level child object is "member".  (The JSON file has to be in this format because I generate it from a Drupal module.)

I extract the member array using this code:

```
var links=members.organizations.map(function(members) {
    return members.member;
});
```

The network works correctly but I am unable to use the category attribute to set the colour of the circles.

How do I access "category" to use in  "fill" and "name" for "text"? (At present, "text" uses the "source" value.)

Comment: For the links it should be something like `d.source.category`.

Comment: Category is not an attribute of the child "source" object ... name, index and others are. Category and the JSON name are attributes of the first level object. When I get to using it to fill the circle all I see is the child attributes.

Comment: What do you mean by "child"? In your JSON sample, the lowest level seems to contain all the attributes.

Comment: This code following the JSON statement changes the json data and links.category becomes undefined:    links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand correctly. Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PatriciaW/6Lezn/

Comment: Thanks, but could you add the data as well please?

Comment: The complete json data is {"organizations":[{"member":{"name":"Green 13","target":"TCAN","category":"community group","source":"G13"}},{"member":{"name":"TCAN","target":"TRSG","category":"organization","source":"TCAN"}},{"member":{"name":"ZCO","target":"TCAN","category":"organization","source":"ZCO"}},{"member":{"name":"Rita Bijons","target":"G13","category":"volunteer","source":"Rita"}},{"member":{"name":"Rita Bijons","target":"ZCO","category":"volunteer","source":"Rita"}}]}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49422/discussion-between-patriciaw-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not putting the category into the nodes you're generating. To do so, modify the code that generates the nodes like this:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.name, category: link.category});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.name, category: link.category});
});
```

This will allow you to color the nodes depending on the category and also adds the correct text. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lezn/3/).

The example doesn't quite work -- the names of the nodes and the source/target strings don't match up and that messes things up. For example, source "G13" doesn't exist (should that be "Green 13"?) and neither does "TRSG".